# How to resize a view to fit a label subview using auto layout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uilabel, autolayout

I'm trying to make a translucent black rectangle with some text in it, to convey some info to users.  It seems to work, but when the phone's text size is large then the label's contents are cut off -- the view won't expand its dimensions.

To create this I added a UIView with a black background and rounded corners, made it somewhat transparent, and placed a UILabel inside it. Constraints on the view should allow it to grow wider when the phone is rotated, and constraints on the label keep its edges pinned to the view.

Here are the view's constraints:

```
Align Center X to: Superview
Align Center Y to: Superview
Trailing Space to: Superview >= 40
Leading Space to: Superview >= 40
Width >= 200
Width <= 300
Height >= 100
Height <= 150
```

And the label's constraints:

```
Trailing Space to: Superview Equals:Default
Leading Space to: Superview Equals:Default
Bottom Space to: Superview Equals:Default
Top Space to: Superview Equals:Default
```

When run on an iPhone 5, the view's size is 200 x 102 for some reason and the text is truncated, even though its constraints allow it to go up to 300 x 150. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27228279/auto-layout-constraint-with-dynamic-variable

Answer (score 0):

Just set UILabel Top/Bottom/Lidding/Trailing constraints to zero because it has intrinsic content size. It means label will wish to become that wide to contain its string value all visible. Look at [this article](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ImplementingView/ImplementingView.html)

Create constraint programmatically

```
_constraint=[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWith...];
[self.view addConstraint:_constraint];
//...
_constraint.constant=40;
```

Use outlet if all the constraints are defined in IB. Just connect it to your constraint.

```
@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *constraint;
```

Comment: Thank you. Setting the UILabel constraints to zero works in that now the UIView widens itself when the phone is rotated, but now there's no padding around the label text; the text is pushed right up to the edge of the view. Setting the Top/Bottom/Leading/Trailing constraints to something like "8" gives a padding, but then the view doesn't resize when the phone is rotated.  

How can I add some padding to the view to make it look more natural?

Comment: @smeep if you connect your constraints to IBOutlets (or keep it as class member) you can change `constant` property as you wish.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. Are you saying to define it in IB as 0 but then change that value in code? I tried that but now the view doesn't resize when the phone is rotated. Maybe my assumption is wrong -- isn't it possible to do what I want purely with auto layout?

Comment: I'm still confused. First you said set the constraints to zero to enable the label to expand, but then you showed an example of setting it to 40. When I set the constant properties to non-zero values then it looks like the view/label doesn't resize correctly when the phone is rotated. Maybe I didn't make my original question clear. I have a gray, translucent view that contains a label. The text is getting truncated, but I don't know if the label isn't properly expanding to allow all the text or if the view isn't properly expanding to allow all the label.

Comment: @smeep If I understand you correct, you need to update your parent view on device rotate, there's no need to change label margins inside your parent view? Your parent view constraints must consist of top and leading ones at all then.