# Auto Layout Constraint With Dynamic Variable?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Is it possible to have an Auto Layout constraint (`NSLayoutConstraint`) with a dynamic constant/multiplier?

For example, this would be a bog standard `NSLayoutConstraint`:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:obj1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:obj2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1 constant:0];
```

Then here would be an alteration of that constraint but a dynamic variable in the constant:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:obj1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:obj2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1 constant:scrollView.contentOffset.x];
```

The second one would take the `contentOffset` of the `scrollview` and use it as the constant. However, having tried this, it only uses the offset which exists when the constraint is made.

What I would want it to have the constraint update the constant, when the scrollview if scrolling. This way it would keep using the most up to date `contentOffset`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes definitely.

In fact, that is what they are built for. When you are animating views etc... you need to be able to change the constraints.

Counter-intuitively the only property of `NSLayoutConstraint` that is writable is the `constant` property. (lol)

You are not quite right in your code though.

Creating the constraint you would first create a property for it...

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSLayoutConstraint *leftConstraint;
```

Then create it...

```
self.leftConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:obj1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:obj2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1 constant:0];
```

Then edit the already existing constraint...

```
self.leftConstraint.constant = scrollView.contentOffset.x;
```

Then you need to force the view to relayout the subviews...

```
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

Comment: Thanks Fogmeister. This works great, although I don't need to call `layoutIfNeeded`, it works without this.

Comment: @JoshKahane OK cool glad you got it working. It can be required sometimes. Animating constraints for instance you need to change the constraints **OUTSIDE** the animation block and then call `layoutIfNeeded` **inside** it. It seems counter-intuitive (today's keyword) so look out for it if you think something's not working.

Comment: Cool thanks. I think the reason I likely didn't need to call it was because I was updating the constant in `scrollViewDidScroll`, as such it was updating frequently enough to need animation.

Comment: @JoshKahane ah yeah, the scroll will be triggering the layout anyway.